# Any alternative for the php function dl()

Tags: php, runtime, extension-methods, soap-client

I need to use `soapClient` in my PHP script it works fine in localhost but when I put it on the remote server It says `dl()` has been disabled for security reasons so is there any other way to load PHP extensions on run time other than change the `php.ini` file?

Comment: There are no alternatives that I know of.  If you don't have access to install extensions and can't use DL, you are pretty much screwed.

Comment: How ridiculous, dl is necessary for the Google Adwords API to work alongside the Analytics OAuth library! They can't be loaded in tandem. Jesus, I've spent 2 months trying to get one to work with the other and they simple won't. The CLI version works using dl('oauth.so'); but not in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Contact your server administrator and have them load the module for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short of supplying your own PHP binary (which you *don't* want to do), no.